# SaaS Scalability - Is Tomcat Scalable enough?

Tags: tomcat, scalability

We are building a SaaS application that will be multi-tenant and is envisaged to have heavy user traffic. The solution will be hosted on Liferay Portal. Liferay out of the box has great support for Tomcat and works well with it. They do have support for other app servers as well. But we are currently leaning towards Tomcat.

The Portal will be mainly a front-end services by webservices living on different App Servers (Glassfish in most cases). We do not need any more J2EE functionality for the portal than that offered by a vanilla tomcat.

Is Tomcat scalable enough to support a multi tenant heavy traffic Saas Application?
I wanted to know what could be the problems we could encounter with Tomcat.

Cheers!
Nirav

Comment: Yes, Tomcat can scale pretty well, and I know of several large-scale systems that run on it. But you seem to be asking if it "scales well enough". Unfortunately I don't know what that means.

Comment: Our typical use case could be about - five portal instances on one app server. Each portal instance supporting one tenant. Each tenant has about 1000 users. So about 5000 users per app server.

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty opinionated question and rather system admin related. That being said, I'd recommend to read Liferay's [performance whitepaper](https://www.liferay.com/de/documentation/additional-resources/whitepapers) which might give you a hint on the actual kind of numbers (and usecases) that you'd like to cover.

I think that tomcat itself - from a performance point of view - scales quite well with Liferay. The cluster administration is what might require some more work than on the "big iron" application servers. So, in general it depends on what you want to scale for. Also, are your users "user accounts" or "concurrent users"?